# Bootstrap 4 Table Issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently making a template with Bootstrap 4. I have a table with four rows, here is the link to the said site: [here](http://file:///C:/Webby/Template12/tour.html).

Now with the CSS I have here for just the links:

```
a {
color: #F0FFFF;
}

a:visited {
color: #00FFFF;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

But at the fourth row, the fourth link does not follow the said CSS rules. My question is did I make a mistake on the CSS? Or does BootStrap 4 have a limit on Tables? With the BootStrap documentation, it shows examples of three rows only. Take a look [here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/).

Comment: can you provide your code what you have tried ??? It will be much easier for us  to understand what you tried .I don't think there is a table row limitation in bootstrap

Comment: Please consider adding your html code, there might be some issue. and you have provided your local path in question which directs to your C: folder in your system. try `plnkr` or `jsbin`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/dauOWEr9XtnDC67xRCNB?p=preview check this

Answer (score 1):

Here is the table HTML:

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-inverse">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Area</th>
  <th>Venue</th>
  <th>Tickets</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <th scope="row">June 16, 2017</th>
  <td>Auburn Hills, MI</td>
  <td><a href="https://www.palacenet.com/">Palace Of Auburn Hills</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
      Tickets!!
    </button></a>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th scope="row">June 19, 2017</th>
  <td>Los Angeles, CA</td>
  <td><a href="http://www.lacoliseum.com/">Los Angeles Memorial Coliseum</a>      </td>
  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
      Tickets!!
    </button></a>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th scope="row">June 23, 2017</th>
  <td>Toyko, Japan</td>
  <td><a href="http://www.nipponbudokan.or.jp/">Nippon Budokan</a></td>
  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
      Tickets!!
    </button></a>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th scope="row">June 26, 2017</th>
  <td>Hong Kong</td>
  <td><a href="#">Hong Kong Festival</a></td>
  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
      Hey!
    </button></a>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: why do you have `</a>` closing anchor tag after button? I couldn't find opening tag. And please use `plnkr` or `jsbin` for code in question itself. Please remove your answer if it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Oddly enough, I have went back to that page without editing the particular page, but played around with the CSS. Now, my problem is no longer a problem, my guess I made a mistake with the CSS. Should I delete?